# Sharepoint sync sets every document to read-only

Tags: document-library, sync, access-rights

I've made some adjustments to the library we are using, but now users can't direct edit the items in the desktop. However, I can.

They see the following:

- Green locks on every document
- When they open a document its in read-only mode
- When they try to upload a new document they are asked for administrator rights.

[image]

How do I fix this? So that every user is able again to edit and upload documents on the fly.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? Kind regards,

Comment: Yes. Disable version control, and disable check-out.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to retain versioning, so i turned version control off, restarted the app, synced a couple of files (green padlock disappeared), enabled version control again, restarted the app, now working fine - no green padlock and files not read only.

Comment: Should have mentioned that check-out was always disabled also.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd just add my 2c here for anyone else. I had this issue and dug through my document library, removing all kinds of custom content types and columns etc. to no avail. What fixed it for me was:

1. Open the document library in Sharepoint Editor
2. Click Edit List columns

[image: Edit List Columns]

3. Delete all custom columns

I added a bunch of custom columns thinking they might be useful... but they were never populated or used. Offline syncing is so much more useful.